# Reading files in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, qstring, qfiledialog

I am building a program in PyQt4 and it requires that data be pulled from multiple text files. I have a button which will select files: it's code being

```
qtCreatorFile = 'parser.ui'

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.file_selector.clicked.connect(self.File_Selector)

        self.log

    def File_Selector(self):
        files_list = []
        filenames = str(QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Select File", "", "*.txt"))
        self.log.insertPlainText('Loading files ' + '\n')
        self.log.insertPlainText(filenames + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MyApp()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the button is pressed I can select the text files I need, but I'm not able to read them? When I ask it to print the filenames in the log it gives me `<PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList object at 0x0000000002BD0BA8>`

I also tried:

```
    text = open(filenames).read()
    self.log.insertPlainText(text)
```

But that gives `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '<PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList object at 0x0000000002F00BA8>` so how do I make the `QStringList object` readable?

Answer (score 3):

`QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(...)` returns a string list, so you can not open it and load it, you have to do it one by one.

```
def File_Selector(self):
    filenames = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Select File", "", "*.txt")
    self.log.insertPlainText('Loading files ' + '\n')
    self.log.insertPlainText(str(filenames) + '\n')
    for filename in filenames:
        text = open(filename).read()
        self.log.insertPlainText(text)
```

Comment: Ahh okay. So if I want to load multiple files I'll have to either get the file path, and then pass that onto another part of the program, or select the directory?